# Making predictions on finetuned InceptionResNetV2

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, dataset, classification

I am trying to make predictions on my test set using my finetuned InceptionResNet2. I am struggling with producing the right input shape for the model. The code that I try to run is:

```
Y_pred = model.predict(test_data)
```

The error that shows up is this:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected
>   global_average_pooling2d_1_input to have shape (8, 8, 1536) but got
>   array with shape (7, 7, 512)

The model that I have used for the finetuning is the following:

```
base_model = InceptionResNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(299,299,3))

top_model = Sequential()
top_model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D(input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:]))
top_model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
top_model.load_weights(top_model_weights_path)

new_model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=top_model(base_model.output))
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is showing up?

Comment: What is the output of `test_data.shape`?

Comment: (1270, 7, 7, 512). Thanks for helping!

Comment: Maybe to add, I got it working before applying the finetuning, but not after the finetuning

Comment: You have specified the input shape of the base model to be `(299,299,3)` and anything you pass to your `new_model` first pass through the `base_model` and then its output is passed to `top_model`. So I think the `test_data` should have a shape of `(?, 299,299,3)`, right?

Comment: I think you have pointed out my problem/mistake. The thing is I have rescaled my data by dividing it by 255. That is the difference I think. I have not done that everywhere accordingly. Let me check!

Comment: The difference must have something to do with this. I just can't figure out where it is going wrong. Would you mind looking at my code if I add it to my first post?

Comment: What do you mean by "difference"? You are getting shape error. Do you still get the same error? It does not have to do with rescaling values. Sure, post your code and I'll take a look at it, but please clearly explain what the problem is.

Comment: Okay today, I have made the most stupid mistake ever. The test_data that I was using came from a a saved file, however I am working with multiple different models in different notebooks and have mixed up the naming of some of my saves. The difference in input shape is explained because I was loading my VGG16 test_data instead of the InceptionResNetV2. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it!